# Getting 403 forbidden with Urlfetchapp on Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

From the start of June 2023, I systematically get 403 response from calling API with `Urlfetchapp`  on Google Apps Script. This code was working fine from several months before.
I'm calling Absorb LMS API ("https://rest.myabsorb.eu/").
The answer is :

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to call Absorb V1 API and Absorb V1.5 API. No difference.
From my script, I call some other API endpoints that are not from Absorb and all is working fine.
When I do my Absorb calls (however the version) from Postman, I have no errors and my calls give me the expected answers.
I saw that I'm not the only one and some others API endpoints are in the same state.

Here is the source code. But as I said, it was working fine and I did no modification since.

```
function getAbsorbToken() { 
  if(absorbToken==null) {
    var sFunction = "Authenticate";
    var sPayload = JSON.stringify({"Username": absorbUsername,"Password": absorbPass,"PrivateKey": absorbPrivateKey});
    var result = callAbsorbAPI(sFunction,"POST",sPayload);
    if(result[0]) { 
      var goodToken = result[1].toString(); 
      goodToken = goodToken.substring(1,goodToken.length-1); 
      absorbToken = goodToken; 
      return true;
    } else { Logger.log("ERROR getAborsbToken"); return false; }
  } else {return true;}
}

function callAbsorbAPI(sFunction, sMethod, sPayload='',sHeaders = "",sGetRequest = "") {
  var url = absorbURL+"api/Rest/v1/"+sFunction;
  if(sGetRequest!="") url += "/"+sGetRequest;
  var headers = {
    'method': sMethod,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };
  if(sPayload != '') {
    headers['payload']=sPayload;
  }
  if(sHeaders != '') {
    headers['headers']=sHeaders;
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers);
  var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  if(responseCode==200 || responseCode == 201) {
    return [true,response];
  } else {
    Logger.log(response+" "+responseCode);
    return [false,response];
  }
}
```

Comment: About the status code 403, it is `The HTTP 403 Forbidden response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.`. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) So, I'm worried that the server of the API might not be able to accept the request of the Google side. But, I'm not sure about the specification of the API you want to use. I apologize for this. So, how about confirming it to the administrator of the API?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I already checked the connection with Absorb support team. And as I said, the API gives answer as well if I do my calls from Postman (and in PHP Curl too).

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I already checked the connection with Absorb support team.`, I couldn't notice it from your question. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike Absolutely no problem.